# Need help in counting total number of entries in a table (Mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, count

I am working on queries in mongodb. One of the queries required require me to find the total number of employees within a database. In this database, there are 2 tables named TRUCK and EMPLOYEE. How can I find the total number of employees within the employee table only?

So far I have tried:

```
db.transport.find.count()
```

Gives total number of entries

```
db.transport.find({"EMPLOYEE.e#"}).count()
```

No output is shown

Any help is appreciated as I have only started learning mongo db this week.

EMPLOYEE:
e#
name
dob
address
hireDate
position
license
status

EMPLOYEE makes TRIP

TRIP
tripNumber
truckRegno
tripDate

Trip has TRIPLEG
cityName

Comment: For counting documents in a collection use [countDocuments](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/index.html).

Comment: i think you are missing the parentheses for `find`. it should be `db.transport.find().count()` instead. what does your schema look like? or where to find the employee field?

Comment: I have posted more info in regards to the database structure. Please check if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look here :

- for modeling in mongodb : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction
- and for querying : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/

In your case, do you have and database "transport" with collections : EMPLOYEE, TRIP, ..?

If it is right so you need only to do :

```
use transport;
db.EMPLOYEE.count()
```

After you cas also do aggregation ... https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/index.html#examples

regards

Comment: I am just tryin to count the entries within a table of the database. Employee is not a separate collection in my case.

Comment: Can you put the description of your database and collections ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use lowercase names for collections (what you call tables).
To answer your question and return total numbers of documents:

```
use transport;
db.EMPLOYEE.countDocuments();
```

Assuming you are using MongoDB > 4.0.3